# Is there any difference between the Ok() method new ObjectResult()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Scenario: implementing a standard REST API / GET method on a .net core controller.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult) states that OkObjectResult is an ObjectResult with status 200. This is available through the `Ok(myResult)` method inherited from ControllerBase. I assume this is a convenience method.

However, the [tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html) is not using this approach - it instead returns `new ObjectResult(myResult)` which will default to status 200.

Is there any difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Technically** there is no difference between the two approaches.

If you want to look at the code of [`OkObjectResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkObjectResult.cs) then you will see that the `OkObjectResult` is an `ObjectResult` that sets the 200 status code, which is the default of `ObjectResult` already.

The only difference for me is **readability in code** and your own or your team preferences. It is all about naming and what intention you want to stress.

```
 return Ok(myResult);                  // gives emphasis on status, my personal favorite

 return new OkObjectResult(myResult);  // for me a little bit verbose and the same
                                       // effect as Ok; but states we return an Object

 return new ObjectResult(myResult);    // gives emphasis of the content that is returned
```

Comment: well, actually it is very misleading answer. Based on this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.1

ApiController has two overloads. Ok return OkResult and Ok<T>(T) returns OkObjectResult. The difference is that OkResult is resulting with status code 200 while OkObjectResult tells that it also returns some value.

Comment: So its not just 'readability in code'. ApiController.Ok method should be always used.

Answer (score 6):

Update:
Both approaches in the original question + the third approach in the accepted answer has now been superseded by simply returning the object directly:

```
 return myResult
```

Relevant example and explanation from the current [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) page:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
{
    var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);    
    if (todoItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }    
    return todoItem;
}
```

> The return type of the GetTodoItems and GetTodoItem methods is ActionResult< T > type. ASP.NET Core automatically serializes the object to JSON and writes the JSON into the body of the response message. The response code for this return type is 200, assuming there are no unhandled exceptions. Unhandled exceptions are translated into 5xx errors.

Comment: How does this work? `todoItem` is not of type `ActionResult<TodoItem>`, but of type `TodoItem`. Why is the compiler not complaining?

Comment: If you need more information than what Microsoft provides in the link above, I suggest you ask your own SO question about this specific part. I don't know the details without looking into it, and a proper answer will probably not fit in a comment anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I can only see the difference in relying on some default value somewhere and providing this value explicitly - the latter is usually better and your intention is much more clear with `OkObjectResult` (or setting `StatusCode` explicitly), which is important enough.
`ObjectResult` does not have default `StatusCode` of 200 - it actually have this value null by default. However, `HttpResponse` has default status code 200, so it works the same anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As a note for who has **unit testing** for his/her code too:

There is a **difference** between `return Ok(myResult)` and `return myResult`!

**When you use `Ok(myResult)`:**
The `Result` property of the returned `ActionResult` object will be filled. So you can write Assertion based on it. Example:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetArticle_ArticleIsNotNull_ReturnsOkObjectResult()
{
    // Arrange
    const int number = 1;
    _articleRepository.GetArticleAsync(number).Returns(new Article());

    // Act
    var result = await _articleController.GetArticle(number);

    // Assert
    result.Result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
}
```

**But if you just use `return myResult`:** the `Result` property remains `null` during your unit testing!