# What's the difference between IActionResult vs OkObjectResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can anyone help me understanding the difference b/w `IActionResult` vs `OkObjectResult`. Because I have webApi method below.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] string userName)
{
     // Some code
     return new OkObjectResult(transactionsBatch);
}
```

And what's the difference between the above code and the below code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get([FromBody] string userName)
{
     // Some code
     return Ok(transactionsBatch);
}
```

Comment: Nothing; convenience: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a386abcb2a62a776abef349dd7ac446dd4e703b3/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L325

Comment: The question should be difference between Ok and OkObjectResult, it has alread been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512053/is-there-any-difference-between-the-ok-method-new-objectresult

Comment: @Caramiriel for the github link. I got the understanding. But one thing in my mind. Will there be any performance issue if write new OkObjectResult(content) vs Ok(content)?

Comment: @Vijay Not significant, unless you are serving 1 billion requests per second. But then you're highly likely to have a different set of problems to worry about. The code is probably the same after JIT'ing anyway.